# You have an error in your SQL syntax error message when inserting record

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the error message when uploading a form in php.

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"

I've followed instructions from other posts as follows, to no avail:

1-Wrapped the column heading names in backticks.
2-Made sure all strings were passed as strings, and ints as ints. 
3-Cleaned up any strings before sending out.
4-Made sure the connection to the database works and we can query from it. 
5-Checked and re-checked my html code.

Here's my php code:

```
<?php

include('../config/config.php');

// Redirect browser if the upload form WAS NOT submited.
if (!isset($_POST['submit_upload']))
{
    header("location: upload.html");
}

// Continue if the upload form WAS SUBMITED

else
{

    // Set the upload directory path

    $target_path = realpath( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . "/uploads/audio/";

    // Array to store validation errors

    $error_msg = array();

    // Validation error flag, if this becomes true we won't upload

    $error_flag = false;
    // We get the data from the upload form

    $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $temp_filename = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $filesize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $mimetype = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    // Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

    $filename = htmlentities($filename);
    $mimetype = htmlentities($mimetype);

    // Check for empty file

    if ($filename == "")
    {
        $error_msg[] = 'No file selected!';
        $error_flag = true;
    }

    // Check the mimetype of the file

    if ($mimetype != "audio/x-mp3" && $mimetype != "audio/mp3")
    {
        $error_msg[] = 'The file you are trying to upload does not contain expected data.  
                Are you sure that the file is an MP3 one?';
        $error_flag = true;
    }

    // Get the file extension, an honest file should have one

    $ext = substr(strrchr($filename, '.') , 1);
    if ($ext != 'mp3')
    {
        $error_msg[] = 'The file type or extention you are trying to upload is not allowed!    
                You can only upload MP3 files to the server!';
        $error_flag = true;
    }

    // Check that the file really is an MP3 file by reading the first few characters of the file

    $open = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');
    $read = @fread($open, 3);
    @fclose($open);
    if ($read != "ID3")
    {
        $error_msg[] = "The file you are trying to upload does not seem to be an MP3 file.";
        $error_flag = true;
    }

    // Now we check the filesize.
    // The file size shouldn't include any other type of character than numbers

    if (!is_numeric($filesize))
    {
       $error_msg[] = 'Bad filesize!';
       $error_flag = true;
    } 

    // If it is too big or too small then we reject it
    // MP3 files should be at least 1MB and no more than 10 MB
    // Check if the file is too large

    if ($filesize > 10485760)
    {
        $error_msg[] = 'The file you are trying to upload is too large!    
            Please upload a smaller MP3 file';
        $error_flag = true;
    }

    // Check if the file is too small

    if ($filesize < 1048600)
    {
        $error_msg[] = 'The file you are trying to upload is too small!  
            It is too small to be a valid MP3 file.';
        $error_flag = true;
    }

    // Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection

    function clean($conn, $str)
    {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }

        return mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $str);
    }

    // Sanitize the POST values

    $title = clean($conn, $_POST['title']);
    $context = clean($conn, $_POST['context']);
    $source = clean($conn, $_POST['source']);
    $interviewer = clean($conn, $_POST['interviewer']);
    $interviewee = clean($conn, $_POST['interviewee']);
    $intervieweeAge = (int)$_POST['intervieweeAge'];
    $geoRegion = clean($conn, $_POST['geoRegion']);
    $language = clean($conn, $_POST['language']);
    $recDate = clean($conn,$_POST['recDate']);
    $keywords = $_POST['keywords'];

    if ($title == '')
    {
        $error_msg[] = 'Title is missing';
        $error_flag = true;
    }

    if ($interviewee == '')
    {
        $error_msg[] = 'Interviewee name/anonymous is missing';
        $error_flag = true;
    }

// If there are input validations, show errors

if ($error_flag == true)
{
    foreach($error_msg as $c => $p) echo "Error " . $c . ": " . $p . "<br />";
}
// Else, all checks are done, move the file.
else
{
    if (is_uploaded_file($temp_filename))
    {
        // Generate an uniqid
        $uniqfilename = $interviewee . '_' . str_replace("_", "", $recDate) . '.mp3'; 
        $filePath = '/uploads/audio/' . $uniqfilename;

        // If the file was moved, change the filename

        if (move_uploaded_file($temp_filename, $target_path . $uniqfilename))
        {

            // Again check that the file exists in the target path
            if (@file_exists($target_path . $uniqfilename))
            {

                // Assign upload date to a variable

                $upload_date = date("Y-m-d");

                // Create INSERT query

                $qry = "INSERT INTO FDM177_AUDIO_CLIPS (title,context,source,interviewer,interviewee,intervieweeAge,geoRegion,language,recDate,fileName,filePath) 
                VALUES('$title','$context','$source','$interviewer',$interviewee',$intervieweeAge,'$geoRegion','$language','$recDate','$uniqfilename','$filePath')";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

                if ($result)
                {
                    $id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                    echo "File uploaded. Now it is called :" . $uniqfilename . "<br />" . $date . "<br />";

                }
                else
                {
                    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
                }

                if(1) {
                    //if (is_array($keywords) || is_object($keywords)) {
                    foreach($keywords as $k) {
                            // $idQuery = "SELECT keyword_ID from KEYWORDS WHERE keywordName=" . $k";
                            $idQuery = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM FDM177_KEYWORDS WHERE (`keywordName` LIKE '%".$k."%')") or die(mysql_error());

                            $matchingKArray = mysqli_fetch_array($idQuery); 

                            $keyword_FK = $matchingKArray[keyword_ID];

                            // echo $kQuery;
                            echo $keyword_FK; 

                            $qry = "INSERT INTO FDM177_JNCT_KWDS_CLIPS (keyword_FK, clip_FK)
                            VALUES ('$keyword_FK', '$id')";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);
                            if ($result)
                            {
                                echo 'inserted with keyword.' . $k . ' <br />';

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "keywords are missing";
                    }




                }
            }
            else {
                echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The problem occurs at the first MYSQL query that starts as MYSQL query INSERT INTO FDM177_AUDIO_CLIPS...

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried renaming the table? thus removing the underscores

Comment: Do you have any apostrophes in your values you are trying to insert?  You may need to escape them with mysql_real_escape_string.  Best practice would be to use prepared statements though: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Please can you copy and paste the error *in full*. Your text cuts off prematurely after "for the right syntax to use near".

Comment: @tjfo *`may`*? `mysql_real_escape_string()` is broken and not secure.

Comment: BTW, you say "Wrapped the column heading names in backticks", but have you also wrapped `FDM177_AUDIO_CLIPS` in backticks?

Comment: @Xorifelse Good catch, I meant mysqli_real_escape_string.

Comment: @tjfo Same same, still broken, just a little less.

Comment: @user2030942 `mysql_error()` does not work with `mysqli`. Perhaps you should use PDO. Than that silly mistake would never have happened.

Comment: instead of `WHERE (\`keywordName\` LIKE '%".$k."%')\` ` try `WHERE keywordName LIKE '%".$k."%' `.

Comment: and try to put your tables' names into `\``\` since they are not single word names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quotes breaking in one query `'$interviewer',$interviewee',`

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO FDM177_AUDIO_CLIPS
                (title, context, source,interviewer, interviewee,
                intervieweeAge,geoRegion,language,recDate,fileName,filePath) 
                VALUES
                ('$title', '$context', '$source', '$interviewer', '$interviewee',
                $intervieweeAge,'$geoRegion','$language','$recDate','$uniqfilename','$filePath')";
```

Comment: your query will not work because it is not written in proper format.

Comment: Thank you! This totally did it for me. Never would have caught it.

Comment: happy to help :)